# Capitalize first letter of all tables in database

Tags: mysql, rename, capitalization

I'm moving databases from windows to Linux and I have the issue of capitalization of table names. While normally, in Linux, the tables have first letter capitalized in windows they all become lower case making it impossible for them to work again in Linux. I can't mess with the servers' sql settings so I'm looking for a query that will solve my problems. After doing some research I combined a few results and ended up with the query below but it doesn't work as the second concat brings out a number. Any solutions?

```
use information_schema;
SELECT 
  CONCAT('RENAME TABLE ', TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', TABLE_NAME, ' TO ', TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', TABLE_NAME = CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(TABLE_NAME, 1)),LCASE(SUBSTRING(TABLE_NAME, 2))), ';')
FROM 
  information_schema.tables  
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = "test";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That TABLE_NAME = is letting you down try:

```
use information_schema;
SELECT 
  CONCAT('RENAME TABLE ', TABLE_SCHEMA, '.', TABLE_NAME, ' TO ', TABLE_SCHEMA, '.',  CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(TABLE_NAME, 1)),LCASE(SUBSTRING(TABLE_NAME, 2))), ';')
FROM 
  information_schema.tables  
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = "test";
```

Comment: Yes I just figured it out. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling recently with this and wrote a stored procedure that takes care of the table's first letter capitalization issue. It uses the `SELECT` statement of the previous answer to populate a temporary table. Then it iterates this temporary table and executes de statements. The procedure is really simple therefor it does not have grammatical intelligence, so that is up to you. 
Here it goes:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `aux_uppercase_tablename`()
PROC: BEGIN
/*
Procedimiento que pone en mayúsculas la primera letra del nombre de las tablas, 
excluyendo las tablas de auditoría (hay que mejorar el script para que lo haga).
No tiene la inteligencia para separar los nombres de tablas formados por dos o mas palabras,
por ejemplo, lineaventa, lineascomprobante, etc.
*/
DECLARE pIndex int;
DECLARE pInstruction varchar(500);
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'Error al procesar.' Mensaje;
        ROLLBACK;
    END;

SET @rowNum = 0;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_instructions;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_instructions ENGINE = MEMORY
    SELECT  (@rowNum := @rowNum + 1) rowNum, CONCAT('RENAME TABLE ', TABLE_NAME, 
               ' TO ' ,CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(TABLE_NAME,1)),SUBSTRING(TABLE_NAME,2)),';') instruction
    FROM    information_schema.TABLES 
    WHERE   TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_schema';


SET pIndex = 1;
WHILE (pIndex <= @rowNum) DO
    SET pInstruction = (SELECT instruction FROM tmp_instructions WHERE rowNum = pIndex);
    SET pIndex = pIndex + 1;

    CALL ssp_eval(pInstruction);

END WHILE;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_instructions;
SELECT 'OK';
END
```

The ssp_eval procedure goes like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `ssp_eval`(pCadena mediumtext)
BEGIN
/*
Permite ejecutar una sentencia preparada leída de la base de datos, 
como implementación de polimorfismo.
*/
-- SELECT pCadena;
SET @Cadena = pCadena;
PREPARE STMT FROM @Cadena;
EXECUTE STMT;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE STMT;
END
```

Hope it work's for everyone with this issue! Greetings.